# Can a Dockerfile push itself to a registry?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

For the use case where a `Dockerfile` needs to be built for each platform it's on (a bit niche I know), is there a way possible for it to push itself to the registry, i.e. calling `docker push` from within the `Dockerfile`?

Currently, this is done:

```
docker build -t my-registry/<username>/<image>:<version> .
docker login my-registry
docker push <image>
```

Could the login and push steps be directly or cleverly built into the Dockerfile being built or with a combination of others?

Note: This would operate in a secure environment of trustworthy users (so all users being able to push to the registry is fine).

Note: This is an irregular use of Docker, not a good idea for building/packaging software in general, rather I am using Docker to share environments between developers.

Comment: "a secure environment of trustworthy users" - until somebody looking at the code says "hey, that's neat, I'll use it for my own project" which gets out into the wild, then some script kiddie says "hey, look, I can write to the registry!" and you've got a killer virus.  Yeah, I want my O/S to work like that...

Comment: @FKEinternet Exactly why we're running this on an internal network :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering why can't you have a wrapper script file (say shell or bat) around the "Dockerfile" to do these steps

```
docker build -t my-registry/<username>/<image>:<version> .
docker login my-registry
docker push <image>
```

What is it so specific about "Dockerfile". I know, this is not addressing the question that you asked, I might have totally misunderstood your usecase, but I am just curious.

As others pointed out, this can be easily achieved using a CD systems like Drone.io/Travis/Jenkins etc.

At first this sounds to me like the decently-circulated ["Nasa's Space pen Myth"](http://www.snopes.com/business/genius/spacepen.asp). But as I said earlier, you may have a proper valid use case which I am not aware of yet.

Comment: +1 I think this is the way to go, admittedly the use case sounds extremely naughty but we're using Docker here to effectively share environments rather than simply software. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Docker build creates image using recipe provided in Dockerfile. Each line in Dockerfile creates new temporary image of file system with different checksum. Image after execution of last line of Dockerfile is your final image of build process and is tagged with provided name.

So it is not possible to put docker push command inside Dockerfile because image creation is not finished yet.

Comment: It would definitely be possible if there was a special `Dockerfile` line, since that wasn't the case I was wondering if someone's done something clever to solve it.

Comment: Isn't that a chicken and egg problem? Even if you added the Docker client to the image and used the necessary `RUN` instructions to push an image of the same tag being built, the image wouldn't have finished being built at the time you push it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `Dockefile` push it's own image will never work.

**To explain a bit more:**

What happens when you build and image: Docker will spawn a container and do everything the `Dockerfile` specifies. You can even see this when running `docker ps` during the build. If the exit status of the container is 0 (no errors), an image is created from the container.

We don't really have much control over this process other than the build parameters. It's definitely a chicken and egg problem.

**Build systems should to this stuff**

It's even fairly easy to do this in Jenkins. The Jenkins setup I have uses a docker plugin and executes build commands to a remote docker hosts.. so the Jenkins nodes only pull the repo, runs a build, then pushes the image to a private repo properly tagged (then deletes the local image). You can run unit tests in docker also by making a separate Dockerfile (gets a bit more complicated when you need external mock services)

Builds per branch/architecture is not too hard to set up. With remote hosts doing the build work we can boost up the job limit in Jenkins fairly high and it can run on cheap hardware.

You can also run Jenkins in docker and make it build images in the docker engine it runs in. I just do that through TLS or the old trick of mapping the socket file into the Jenkins container might still work.

I think I started with the [CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Build+and+Publish+plugin) and it was fairly easy to use, but now I use a custom plugin so I have no idea of the alternatives.